# bash I/O redirection sequence

Tags: bash, redirect

I'm writing bash script redirecting several outputs to files, later reading files in order they were written. I found that sometimes one of the redirection is done writing **after** the consecutive redirection is complete. e.g. line 2 is complete prior to line 1.

```
line 1:   a > a1
line 2:   b > b1
```

Idling between the lines using "sleep" worked around it, but that's a very poor solution. For some reason "wait" doesn't work. What would be the proper solution? Why "wait" function doesn't work?

Thanks!

**edited:**

I'm a bit ashamed with my scripting skills, but here's part of the #!/bin/bash:

```
grep Alpha output.dat | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 > ./$run_dir/Alpha
grep Beta output.dat | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d'.' -f1 > ./$run_dir/Beta
grep flap output.dat | cut -d'=' -f2 > ./$run_dir/flap_angle
grep CLtot output.dat | cut -d'=' -f2 > ./$run_dir/CLtot
grep CYtot output.dat | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -c-10 > ./$run_dir/CYtot
grep Cltot output.dat | cut -d'=' -f3 | cut -c-10 > ./$run_dir/Cltot
grep Cmtot output.dat | cut -d'=' -f3 | cut -c-10 > ./$run_dir/Cmtot
grep Cntot output.dat | cut -d'=' -f3 | cut -c-10 > ./$run_dir/Cntot
ls -tr ./$run_dir > ./$run_dir/files_string
cd ./$run_dir
octave ../assemble_matrix.m
```

Running octave I rely on the order of file names in 'files_string' to assemble a matrix of numeric values in CLtot,CYtot etc . Sometimes I get that 'files_string' is written before 'Cntot', and while calling the second to last file I expect numeric values (from 'Cntot') but I get chars (from 'files_string').
Needless to say it happens between the numeric values as well - it doesn't crash my code, but it still causes a logical error.

Comment: Are these writes in different processes or sub-shells?  How do you know the order is different?  Are some writing via stderr (which is non-buffered) vs stdout (which is buffered).

Comment: If you're not running the programs in the background, there's no way that line 2 can complete before line 1. The shell executes commands in order, and doesn't start line 2 until line 1 is done.

Comment: Unless `a` is a program that forks its own child processes that run in the background. What is the actual command that you're running on line 1?

Comment: Please provide more details, e.g. a piece of the bash script that exhibits your behavior

Comment: `wait` only works on background processes started by the current shell.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Your current problem description is not readily understandable.

Comment: @Barmar "The shell executes commands in order" - That's what I thought. as you see the code is pretty straight forward, no forking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I edited to include the relevant code section. If that won't do, I will try to reproduce the problem with an MCVE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File modification time granularity is only to the second. If `ls` runs quickly enough the timestamp of `files_string` will be the same as `Cntot`, so the `-t` option won't force a specific ordering between them. For files with the same timestamp, it orders them by name.

Use a name for `files_string` that's alphabetically after `Cntot` and you should get the correct result.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a shot `a > a1 && b > b1`

Comment: This prevents `b` from running if `a` gets an error. But if `a` runs code in the background, this won't change that.